# construct a fibre bundle out of $(E,\pi,M,F,G)$ -- from an old one to a new one

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

In Book of GEOMETRY, TOPOLOGY and PHYSICS of Mikio Nakahara 2nd Edition, p.353-354, he described the reconstruction of fibre
$$(E,\pi,M,F,G)$$
total space $E$, projection $\pi$, base $M$, fiber $F$, structure group $G$.

my own questions:

1. He said that the given data reconstruct a fibre bundle $E$ "uniquely." How do we show that it is uniquely constructed? Why not other possible fibre bundles?
2. How is the trivialization $\phi_i$ given by the above given data $(E,\pi,M,F,G)$? It is not obvious $$\phi_i: U_i \times F \to \pi^{-1}(U_i)$$ is determined by  $(E,\pi,M,F,G)$...?
3. He said that: This procedure may be employed to **construct a new fibre bundle from an old one.**  Isn't this claim kind of conflict with that the reconstruction of a fibre bundle $E$ "uniquely"? If not, what data requires to change among  $(E,\pi,M,F,G)$ to **construct a new fibre bundle from an old one?** I don't think it is changing the trivialization $\phi_i$ because which is a gauge transformation.

To make sure everyone follow his statement, I attach Nakahara 9.2.2 below.

---

[image]

[image]